# java http GET - result parsing

Tags: java, json, parsing, bufferedreader, http-get

With my application I am connecting to a php scrip which is on http server (GET method). I am reading a result with buffer reader.

```
 public String updateOsv(String urlToRead) {
  URL url;
  HttpURLConnection conn;
  BufferedReader rd;
  String line = null;
  String result = "";
  try {
     url = new URL(urlToRead);
     conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
       // System.out.println(result);
    }
     rd.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
 }
```

The exact result is this: 15;1;20. How can i parse this result if i want to have those 3 numbers in separate variables (int i=15, int j=1, int k=20)?  Please help me. I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't has a function like PHP `list` which you can `explode` a value and assign it to different variables in one simple instruction. Instead, you may create an array using [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), a sample would be:

```
String[] values = resultString.split(";");
```

Comment: Thank you. This really works. Can you help me one more time please? I have this "updateOsv" method in one class called Update. When I get those values I want to use them in my GUI class. Is there a possibility to pass them throuh a object of my Update class? Sorry for my english. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: of course, you could in the simplest way use the array (`values`) as parameter or return value.

Comment: Sorry it seems, that I dont have so excelent knowledge, but if I try to make it like this: return values, instead of return result, it says that It has to return String and not String[]

Comment: you could change the method to `public String[] updateOsv(String urlToRead)` and where you invoke it will receive an array of string, which are the separated values